# readOnlyInput doesn't work in PrimeFaces p:calendar

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I use this (PrimeFaces, Java, JSF):

```html
<p:calendar id="popupCal" yearRange="c:c+1" lang="fr" required="true"
            requiredMessage="Date obligatoire" readonlyInput="true"
            navigator="true" pattern="dd-M-yyyy" locale="fr"
            showOn="both" value="#{commandeMB.commande.dateCmd}"
            mindate="#{commandeMB.todaysDate}" />
```

and as I wrote, I set `readonlyInput` to `true`.

I tested also `readonly` to `true` and both to `true` but no result, always the date can be changed.

Is it a bug?

Comment: What version are you using? Note that `p:calendar` is deprecated. Please use `p:datePicker` instead.

Answer (score 6):

If you want that user must not be able to change the value of the Calender Dates, just view it then use `showOn="none"` and `readonly="true"` in `p:calender` attribute, I have used it and its working (I'm using Primefaces 5.0 hope it works on all versions) :

Answer (score 1):

`readonly` is used when you just allow user use panel to pick date and can not change date from input. If you want user can not change date, you have to use `disabled` attribute to do that.

If you want user can see date picker and can not change date, you can disable dateselectevent via:

```
<p:calendar onfocus="$('#ui-datepicker-div td').unbind();" readonly="true"/>
```

Comment: but with disable, the component doesn't appear well

Comment: @begiPass: So what do you want ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I've found the issue to be casing.  In our app, it's readonlyInput and that's where it works.  readOnlyInput does not.

Answer (score 0):

With **PF 3.4**, this solution will:

- Retain 1.0 opacity on a readonly text input field 
  (i.e., don't dim opacity with disabled=true);
- Remove the Datepicker class from the field;
- Unbind events from the field.

  ---

(1) Create a function:

`function setCalendarVis(readOnly) {
  if(readOnly)
    $('input:text').removeClass('hasDatepicker').unbind();
}`

(2) Define a calendar component:

`<p:calendar readonly="#{bean.readonly}" value="#{bean.datefield}" mode="popup"/>`

(3)
Call the function, for example, maybe via an ajax event on a p:databable:

`<p:ajax event="rowDblselect" update="@form" oncomplete="setCalendarVis(#{bean.readonly});"/>`

My app uses different styles for read and write capability:
[image]

*My use of unbind() is rather brute force.  You can refine it to unbind only particular events*.

Flame suit on!

Answer (score -2):

Just add `[readonlyInput]="true"` attribute in the input.

Example:

```
 <p-calendar [readonlyInput]="true">
```

Comment: The question is about PrimeFaces, not PrimeNG.

Answer (score -2):

This is how I achieved read only behaviour:

```
<p-calendar [readonlyInput]="true" [showOnFocus]="false">
```

Comment: The question is about PrimeFaces, not PrimeNG.